# wbadmin - Recovering a vhdx file without overwritting the host VM

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-backup, wbadmin

I need to restore a vhdx file from backup on a Windows 2019 Hyper-V Core server using the command line. This is the command I am using:

```
wbadmin start recovery -version:10/12/2021-05:00 -itemType:hyperV -items:F3D...1E -recoveryTarget:C:\temp
```

The command generates the following warnings. After which I am prompted to continue with the restore or cancel it.

> Warning: If a Virtual Machine you are trying to recover to alternate
> location was backed up from this host, this will delete and overwrite
> the original virtual machine if it still exists.
>
> You have chosen to recover the application HyperV. The files for the
> following components will be recovered to C:\temp. Note: Recovering
> the files to an alternate location without involving writer will not
> recover the application.
>
> Warning: The virtual machines might not start if their network
> settings are different after recovery. After recovery is complete use
> Hyper-V Manager to verify the network settings of the virtual machines
> before they are started.

I do not want the restore operation to delete and overwrite the original VM as it states in the warning. Further the warning seems to be contradictory. The scenario I would like to have play out is written in the Note as I am assuming that "...without involving the writer the application will not recover the application" possibly means that wbadmin will despite its warning, not overwrite the VM on the host. I cannot find any information on this online.

Furthermore there is an [-alternateLocation] option to the wbadmin start recovery command that is poorly documented. It does not even seem to be included in the official Microsoft documentation online.

```
-alternateLocation  Valid only when recovering HyperV to alternate recovery target.
                    Allows recovering the HyperV components, updating configuration and
                    registering the VM with the Hyper-V management service.
```

Using it slightly changes the warnings I get, namely the Note is ommitted.

> Warning: If a Virtual Machine you are trying to recover to alternate
> location was backed up from this host, this will delete and overwrite
> the original virtual machine if it still exists.
>
> You have chosen to recover the application HyperV. The files for the
> following components will be recovered to C:\temp.
>
> Warning: If a Virtual Machine you are trying to recover to alternate
> location was backed up from this host, this will delete and overwrite
> the original virtual machine if it still exists.
>
> Warning: The virtual machines might not start if their network
> settings are different after recovery. After recovery is complete use
> Hyper-V Manager to verify the network settings of the virtual machines
> before they are started.

What I want to achive is basicaly a "Copy To File" as is found in the GUI version (Windows Server Backup) and I suspect the way to achieve this is by omitting the [-alternateLocation] option. I would like to see if anyone can confirm this before I pull the trigger and shoot myself in the foot. BTW I'm talking about an in production domain controller VM. So I cannot take any chances.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're just looking to recover a file from the backup consider mounting the backup VHDX read-only and just copying the file your need from the backup. Mounting a specific version can be a little more involved than just mounting the last backup since you'll need to expose the snapshot first.

- Do a `wbadmin show versions` and locate the GUID of the "Snapshot ID" you need to expose. I'd recommend placing this on your clipboard.
- Run `diskshadow` and at the `DISKSHADOW>` prompt enter `expose {Snapshot ID} x:` where "x:" is the drive letter you'd like to expose the snapshot under. The clipboard comes in handy here. I will typically leave `diskshadow` running and continue with the process (because it's needed later).
- Use your favorite method to mount the backup VHDX from the drive letter where you exposed the shadow. I will typically use Powershell and do something like `$x = Mount-VHD -Path <<VHDX PATH>> -ReadOnly -Passthru` so I have the mount details saved in a variable for later.
- You can make sure the newly-mounted volume wasn't assigned a drive letter automatically in Powershell (assuming you mounted the disk as I did above) with `$z = Get-Disk -Number $x.Number | Get-Partiton | Get-Volume` and a `$z` to see what was returned.
- You may want to assign the volume a drive letter. I find that frustrating with pure Powershell so I end up doing something like `mountvol r: $z.UniqueId` where "r:" is the drive letter I want to assign to the mounted backup VHDX.
- Finally, having exposed the snapshot and mounted the backup VHDX you can access the volume via the drive letter you assigned and copy the file you need.
- To tear all of this back down I would do `mountvol r: /r` to remove the drive letter from the mounted backup VHDX. I would dismount the VHDX using `$x | Dismount-VHD`. Finally, I'd flip back to `diskshadow` and do an `UNEXPOSE X:` to unexpose the snapshot. That puts the machine back in the state I found it.